# Accessing an IBOutlet from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am new to Swift/iOS, so please bear with me:

I am trying to access a function in one class from another class, and update an UIImage name.

Within my viewcontroller class I have

```
class Documents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var UpdateImage: UIImageView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UpdateImage()
    }

    func UpdateImage() {
        UpdateImage.image = UIImage(named: "NewImage")
    }
}
```

Everything works, the Image gets updated to "NewImage"

Question: I can access the UpdateImage func from another class, but why is it generating an error when trying to change the image in the Documents class?

```
class GetChanges {

    var success = { operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response:AnyObject!) -> Void in

        var MakeChange = Documents()
        MakeChange.UpdateImage()

    }
}
```

This generates an error on the "UpdateImage.image = UIImage(named: "NewImage")" in the Documents Class; "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 5):

When you call it within the class itself, it is operating on itself and it has already been created from a nib/storyboard.  This means that `UpdateImage` exists.

When you call the method from another class, when you call this line:

`var MakeChange = Documents()`

You are creating a new instance of `Documents`.  This is not initialized through the nib/storyboard, and thus it never populated the `IBOutlet` value `UpdateImage`.  Because this value doesn't exist, it unexpectedly finds `nil` and throws an error.

You need to somehow retain a reference to the instance of `Documents` you're trying to display.  I'd need more information to tell you how to do that.

Also, because you mentioned that you're new, I'd like to point out a few issues I notice with your code that is making it very difficult to read.

1. Capitalized names are reserved for `Types` variable names should (almost) never begin with a capital letter.
2. Variable names should reflect the object they represent.  `UpdateImage` sounds like it is an image.  It would be better to name this `updateImageView`
3. Functions should be lowercase as well.  It is strange to see capitalization this way and makes the code a bit uncomfortable to read.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comments re: the Readability of my code, I am coming from another language, so I will observe these issues going forward...  But this doesn't really solve the issue I am having.

Comment: @MrSparkle2014 I figured so much, but did my comments about maintaining a reference to the specific instance of `Documents` help?

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not help me.

Comment: @MrSparkle2014 - No reason to be sassy, I'm only trying to help.  I told you specifically that I'd need more information if you want help in solving your problem.  Nobody can answer your question with the given information because you don't understand the concept.  If you want help, elaborate as I offered.  There is a reason that nobody else answered this question and it has nothing to do with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read about View Contoller's lifecycle, it's very important knowledge for iOS developer.

As Logan said:

> You are creating a new instance of Documents. This is not initialized through the nib/storyboard, and thus it never populated the IBOutlet value UpdateImage

This means that after call `init` for ViewController (i.e. `Documents()`) `nib` isn't loaded. You can use outlets of viewController in another code only after `viewDidLoad` stage. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the viewDidLoad() method and perform your tasks there.

You can remove `MakeChange.UpdateImage()`, because it will be called in `viewDidLoad`. Or, if you want pass specific image name to view controller:

```
class Documents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 

    UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var UpdateImage: UIImageView
        var imageName: String?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            updateImageView()
        }

        func updateImageView() {
            if let imageName = imageName {
                UpdateImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, you can use

```
let documentsViewController = Documents
documentsViewController.imageName = "newImage"
```

When you load documentsViewController, newImage will be presented